# Signing arc diff commits without using git config commit.gpgsign

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist, gpg-signature

Is there a way to get `arc diff` to submit a signed diff commit like `git commit -S` does? I know that `git config commit.gpgsign true` will get `arc diff` to start signing commits, but I'm looking for some way that won't start trying to sign everything else I do in that repository if I forget to turn `commit.gpgsign` off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a custom shell script, that run these commands you mentioned in order and use it for singed commits, an example would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
git config commit.gpgsign true
path-to-arc-bin diff
git config commit.gpgsign false
```

and save it as `arc-diff-signed` command. And link it to `/usr/local/bin/` so you conveniently run it in shell where ever you are.